# When directly changing v-model in Vue, value in the Vuetify component on the screen does not get refreshed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my example Vue component (I am using Vue 2 and Vuetify 1) I have an input field where user can input data, but I want to be able to programmatically change data in the input field to be of desired value.

In this example, I want value of the input field to allways be "1" regardless of what user types in the input field (I know this is pointless, but this is just a bare minimum working example to demonstrate my problem on a more complex use case).

Here is an example:

```js
<script>
    export default
    {
        data() { return { v: null } },
        computed:
        {
            c:
            {
                get() { return this.v; },
                set(v) { this.v = "1"; }
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<template>
    <v-text-field v-model = "c" />
</template>
```

However, this example does not work. Whatever user inputs in the input field is retained in the input field. Setter does fire, and the value of the `v` property does indeed change. But on the screen, the value in the text field does not change.

What is the problem here?

**NOTE:**

I already seen an answer to a similar question where it was suggested to use the `set` method to set the value of the `v-model`. However, this solution does not work for me. I tried using `return { o: { v: null }}` in the `data` section and the `set(v) { this.$set(this.o, "v", "1"); }` in the `computed` section, but in my case it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reetting the value on the `input` event should hopefully achieve what you want.

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        v: 1,
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="v" @input="v = 1" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpNzcEKgzAQBNBfWfbUQjXY1ovE0n5H7SGYFYSoIW6CIP57o8W2t3kDwzxnHF0tHtamwRMWKMfatZZvVQ9Akx0cg6ZGecMwrx2AVqwOx10Ajti7/meAUEB22rl8wrIVEVJ8HyKYOmsU0/YnQ8I0cdK0ZDSEpBs0mbLCUCHc2956XgElZLEQcSLF3x6XE17Sa5rluIY8PePrDXjpQ9c=)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for an answer. Unfortunately, this does not solve my issue. Whatever user inputs in the browser is still displayed on the screen. I need this user's input to be replaced by 1, so that user never sees anything else on the screen.

Comment: I see my original answer wasn't exactly what you needed.  Try my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not understand how but the exact same code which you provided does not work in my case. In your demo it works, but if I put it as a component in my project it does not work. Still, user input is visible.

It might be because I am using Vue 2 and Vuetify 1 and your demo uses newer versions. It might be some bug they fixed in the later versions or something.